# How to move position of an inserted image in Wordrpess to any direction?

Tags: wordpress

In Microsoft Word, if you insert an image and then right click on it, under 'Wrap Text' and then select 'Tight' and click on it. By doing that you can drag and move the inserted image anywhere in the word page to your liking.

I was trying to do the same thing in Wordpress. After I insert the image inside the paragraph text box in Wordpress, I tried to move the inserted image position to anywhere wherever I want to but it didn't work. I also right clicked on inserted image but it has limited options unlike Word.

How do I fix this issue that I am facing ?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are the theme you're using either does not specify the css for the added classes, or they are overwritten and the default formatting is no longer being used. Here are some basic css classes you can add to style.css (assuming your theme is queuing style.css)

```
.alignleft{
    max-width:50%;
    float:left;
    margin:.3em 3em 3em 0;
    height:auto;
}

.alignright{
    max-width:50%;
    float:right;
    margin:.3em 0 3em 3em;
    height:auto;
}

.aligncenter, .alignnone{
    max-width:100%;
    margin:1em auto;
    height:auto;
}
```

You can adjust the margins to match your needs, but that's the basic idea. When you align using the wordpress WYSIWYG it just adds classes to the images. Those classes are alignleft, alignright, and aligncenter or alignnone

When you click an image in the editor you get this little toolbar with some icons. Hover over the icons to see the format they are triggering. Here's a simple screenshot.

[image]